# create kafka topic using debezium commectors for tables with special character

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium, debezium-engine

I need to create kafka topic using debezium commectors for tables with special character.
My table name is all_bus$.
But when added in the connector as below no topic is getting created in confluent.
Note: My source table is in Sql Server.

```
 "table.include.list": "dbo.all_bus$"
```

Is there any solution for this.

I also tried like below but still no topic is getting created.

```
"'dbo.all_bus$'"
"dbo.'all_bus$'"
```

Comment: What is your connector configuration? 
Your question needs more details

Answer (score 0):

Kafka topics themselves cannot have dollar signs. That's probably why it is not created. You should check the Debezium server logs for errors.

You can try using RegexRouter to fix this.